# Applying Angular Acceleration in a Basic Physics Model

Tags: physics, xna-4.0, torque

I'm attempting to use a basic physics system to create an arcade flight model. So far I have managed to get the aircraft moving forward, apply gravity, etc. However, after trying to implement torque I noticed some interesting behaviour in the flight model. When turning after a while the controls appear to reverse, sometimes, the controls for the different movements (pitch, roll, yaw) also seem to change. I was hoping that someone may be able to advise me as to what I should check next. I have included my source code in case anyone spots any glaring mistakes! I have listed some of the variables below to show their data types:

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Identity;
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Identity;
Vector3 rotationChange = Vector3.Zero;
Vector3 rotVec = Vector3.Zero;
```

Below is the update logic for the rotational forces:

```
dt = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
if (dt > 1.0f / 60.0f)
{
    dt = 1.0f / 60.0f;
}

Vector3 newRotationChange = rotationChange + dt * angularAcceleration;
Vector3 newRotVec = rotVec + dt * newRotationChange;

rotationChange = newRotationChange;
rotVec = newRotVec;

Vector3 rotAxis = rotVec;
rotAxis.Normalize();

if (rotVec.Length() < 0.001f)
{
    rotVec = Vector3.Zero;
    newRotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(forwardVector, 0.0f);
}
else
{
    float angle = rotVec.Length();
    newRotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(rotAxis, angle);
}

if (rotationChange.Length() < 0.001f)
{
    rotationChange = Vector3.Zero;
}

rotation = newRotation;
angularAcceleration = Vector3.Zero;
```

My method for creating the torque:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a rotational force for an object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pointOfAction">Point the force is being applied on the object
/// </param>
/// <param name="forceAmount">Magnitude of the force being applied</param>
/// <param name="forceDir">Direction of the force being applied</param>
public void CreateTorque(Vector3 pointOfAction, float forceAmount, Vector3
        forceDir)
{
    // Vector from position to pointOfAction
    Vector3 r = pointOfAction - position;

    // Create the force
    Vector3 force = forceDir * forceAmount;

    // Create the torque force
    torque = Vector3.Cross(r, force);

    angularAcceleration += torque;
}
```

Sorry for the massive code block and thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: When you apply a crossproduct you have to keep in mind that there are 2 vectors that are normal to the plane defined by the 2 vectors. Crossproduct will return one of them based on the angle between the two vectors. It is likely that it flips when it hits the point where the crossproduct returns the other normal.

Comment: Hi @RobCurr thanks for your feedback. Could you suggest a method for counteracting this? Again, thanks for your response.

Comment: I managed it in my own project by checking the sign of the y component of the resulting normal vector but my case was different in that my game object was constrained in space which is not the case for yours.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RobCurr this has at least given me a pointer as to where to look next!

Comment: @RobCurr The cross product will never 'randomly' start returning the other normal; while there are two normals to the plane, the cross-product is a well-defined function of the two vectors being crossed, and you can't expect arbitrarily flipping it to do the right thing.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more specifically?  What exactly precedes error, and what happens to all your different motions after the "flip"?  If you can post a video that includes your input, great.  
Also, can you put more code up?  If you're willing, post the whole class, or even your whole project (not here though, find a pastebin or version control site).

Comment: By the way, if your single rotation affects all your other rotations, the problem must be common to all three.  I suspect that your `forwardVector` somehow flips negative, or something along those lines.  Your `CreateTorque` method can add a vector of either sign, so it's possible your accumulation of rotation goes below zero, which would make all related rotation appear to be reversed.  It's difficult to say without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't believe I used the word randomly ever. I simply stated that there are two vectors that are normal to the plane defined by the 2 input vectors and that the angle between those vectors will determine which one you get. Please explain how this is incorrect. In my own game I was able to detect this situation and correct for it but as I stated that likely wont work for this situation because his is not limited as mine was. Please read before replying next time.

Comment: Hi @SethBattin I'm afraid I can't upload the code at the moment as I don't have access to it. However, while attempting to debug this problem I found that the handling was fine while the length of 'rotVec' was below 1. As soon as this value goes over 1 the strange handling occurs. I wondered whether or not this could be _looping_ the rotation values? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @SethBattin I have the entire project uploaded to SkyDrive and can PM you a link if you are still interested in helping. I tried changing angularAcceleration to a Quaternion during the update step to calculate the rotation but this caused a shearing behaviour when the aircraft drew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I finally managed to work out what I was doing wrong.
The issue was how I was applying the rotation vector to the quaternion. Basically rather than use `Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle()` I now create a rotation change Quaternion using my angular velocity as the X,Y,Z components and 0 for the scalar. So just for clarity here is my new update code for rotational physics. ( This replaces every line of code after calculating `dt`)

```
Vector3 newAngularVelocity = angularVelocity + dt * angularAcceleration;
Quaternion rotChange = 
    new Quaternion(angularVelocity.X, angularVelocity.Y, angularVelocity.z, 0);
rotChange = Quaternion.Multiply(rotChange, dampeningFactor) * rotation;
rotation += rotChange * dt;
rotation.Normalize();

angularVelocity = newAngularVelocity;
angularAcceleration = Vector3.Zero;
```

Hopefully this proves helpful to someone else!

Comment: it appears that what I was considering a 'dampening factor' actually requires a particular value. This needs to be 0.5 otherwise the code does not acheive the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use `.CreateFromAxisAngle()` it is necessary to supply a unit length vector for the `axis` param. If you don't, it will over or under rotate the result since the axis magnitude is a factor in the rotation calculation.

Try normalizing it like this:

```
else
{
    float angle = rotVec.Length();
    rotVec /= angle;//this normalizes rotVec
    newRotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(rotVec, angle);// use 'rotVec' as the axis, not rotAxis
}
```

Comment: Hi @Steve H, I have tried the modifications you have suggested but it still produces the same behaviour. I was wondering whether or not the rotation quaternion could be looping? Thanks for your response.

Comment: I think the original code already did what you suggested.  It does it using `Vector3.Normalize()`, rather than dividing the vector by its length.  The library method probably prevents divide by zero errors, but yours will not.