# Applying angular velocity distorts model

Tags: physics, rotation, rigid-body-dynamics

I am calculating the orientation of a sphere through the following code

```
wV = new Vector3(0, pi/2, 0);
w = new Quaternion(wV, 0);
// o is the current Orientation
o.Normalize();
w = 0.5f * w * o;
// dt is the elapsed time since the last frame
o += w * dt;
```

However it seems that over time the sphere tends to become distorted and then shrink back to its original size. Is this due to the simplicity of the integration or am I doing some simple mistake?

Comment: I don't think that quat constructor does what you think it does

Comment: What should it be doing? I've seen multiple times converting the angular velocity vector in quaternion form by setting w to 0, e.g.: this [answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/54575/33000).